# force break in flex box and display item to next column

Tags: html, css, flexbox

there is a flexbox that fill items in multiple column based on max height of box.
i want to force break in one of the items in flexbox and display in first position of next column.
I showed this in the picture below.

```css
.flex{
  display:flex;
  flex-direction:column;
  flex-wrap:wrap;
  max-height:200px;
  width:600px;
    background:#fafafa;
}
.item{
  background:#ddd;
  height: 30px;
  width: 100px;
  margin-bottom:5px;
}
.gonextColumn {
  background:#000
}
```

```html
<div class="flex">
  <div class="item"></div>
   <div class="item"></div>
   <div class="item"></div>
   <div class="item"></div>
   <div class="item"></div>
   <div class="item"></div>
   <div class="item"></div>
   <div class="item"></div>
  <div class="item gonextColumn"></div>
   <div class="item"></div>
   <div class="item"></div>
   <div class="item"></div>
   <div class="item"></div>
   <div class="item"></div>
   <div class="item"></div>
   <div class="item"></div>
   <div class="item"></div>
</div>
```

[image]

https://codepen.io/mkkdev/pen/RwNzQXK

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can consider a margin *hack* like below:

```css
.flex{
  display:flex;
  flex-direction:column;
  flex-wrap:wrap;
  max-height:200px;
  width:600px;
    background:#fafafa;
}
.item{
  background:#ddd;
  height: 30px;
  width: 100px;
  margin-bottom:5px;
}
.gonextColumn {
  background:#000;
  margin-bottom:200px; /* a big value here */
}
.gonextColumn + * {
  margin-top:-195px; /* the opposite of the big value minus the real margin*/
}
```

```html
<div class="flex">
  <div class="item"></div>
   <div class="item"></div>
   <div class="item"></div>
   <div class="item"></div>
   <div class="item"></div>
   <div class="item"></div>
   <div class="item"></div>
   <div class="item"></div>
  <div class="item gonextColumn"></div>
   <div class="item"></div>
   <div class="item"></div>
   <div class="item"></div>
   <div class="item"></div>
   <div class="item "></div>
   <div class="item"></div>
   <div class="item gonextColumn"></div>
   <div class="item "></div>
</div>
```